# Ajax+PHP "Unknown column 'team' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to using Ajax and PHP to insert data into a MYSQL database. 
Here is the problematic PHP code.

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO entries 
(team,color,auto,defense,scale,score,cards) VALUES 
('$team','$color','$auto','$defense','$scale','$score','$cards')");
```

My guess is that the PHP variables (which I am getting using $_POST[""]) are not being POSTed properly from Ajax (which is as follows):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "(something)",
data:{team:team,color:color,auto:auto,defense:defense,scale:scale,climb:climb,speed:speed,score:score,cards:cards}
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Share table structure

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks to me like your MySQL database table “entries” does not have a column named “team”.

Have you quadruple-checked the column name against the query code?

Answer (score 0):

you can see the posted data using browser console to check that is properly posted or not in ajax call and check your `entries` table structure.